# JS: get value of element in ajax updated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page with a div updated with Ajax request as needed; this div contains an input with dynamic name that I need to get data from. The button and the script that need this data are placed on the main page. When I try to get data with scripts placed in the updated div html itself, it works fine; but same code placed on the main page does not work. How do I find an element by id in Ajax updated div?

Main page:

```
/* ajax updated div */
<span id="i_descr_{{i.id}}" class="tooltiptext"></span>
/* button */
<div class="trade_move arrow_r" item_id="{{i.id}}" partner_id="{{data.partner_id}}"></div>
<script>
$(".trade_move").click(function() {
            var item_id = $(this).attr("item_id");
            var partner_id = $(this).attr("partner_id");
            var quantity = 1;
            var sliderElem = document.getElementById("slider_".concat($(this).attr("item_id")));
            if (sliderElem) {
                quantity = sliderElem.value;
            }
}
</script>
```

Ajax template, input part:

```
<input class="slider" type="range" item_id="{{description.id}}" id="slider_{{description.id}}" min="0" max="{{description.slider}}" value="{{description.slider}}" step="1">
```

If I put the button and the script into the ajax template, they work just fine; is it possible to address the input by its id from main page, loaded before the ajax part?

edit: 
I tried adding the button press script to ajax unction that updates the div as by suggestion from Arathi Sreekumar, but it behaves same as before. It also does not work unless you actually load the div with the slider now, meaning it comes from ajax function and not somewhere else. Could I get the syntax wrong or something?

```
$(".item_description").hover(function(){
                 var param = $(this).attr("d_id");
                 $.get('/sud/item_na/', {id: param}, function (data) {
                     $('#i_descr_'.concat(param)).html(data);

                     $(".trade_move").click(function() {
                        var item_id = $(this).attr("item_id");
                        var quantity = 1;
                        var sliderElem = document.getElementById("slider_".concat($(this).attr("item_id")));
                        if (sliderElem) {
                            quantity = sliderElem.value;
                        }
                        $.ajax({
                             ...
                        });
                    });
         });
```

edit2: I got it working, not exactly how I wanted it initially, but still. 
I did not go into details about the general layout but to make things clear:
1) Layer 1: main page with empty div and a button
2) Layer 2: empty div on main page is populated with ajax html generated by button press. This html is a list of items, each coming with an empty tooltip div, that on hover triggers another ajax query and populates it with item info.
3) Layer 3: Item info window which has the slider control and the button to do something with the item, considering the slider value (and item id naturally).

I put the button and the script attached to it into the last layer 3 template. Here goes the code:

```
<div align="left">
        <input class="slider_value" id="slider_value_{{description.id}}" type="number" value="{{description.slider}}" disabled>
        <input class="slider" type="range" item_id="{{description.id}}" id="slider_{{description.id}}" min="0" max="{{description.slider}}" value="{{description.slider}}" step="1">
        <div class="trade_move_slider arrow_r" id="trade_move_slider_button_{{description.id}}" item_id="{{description.id}}" partner_id="{{description.partner_id}}" quantity="{{description.slider}}" style="width: 30px;height: 20px;display: inline-block;">
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".slider").change(function() {
            $("#slider_value_".concat($(this).attr("item_id"))).val($(this).val());
            $("#trade_move_slider_button_".concat($(this).attr("item_id"))).attr("quantity", $(this).val());
        });

        $(".trade_move_slider").click(function() {
            $('#output').html('<span class="dot"></span><span class="dot"></span><span class="dot"></span>');
            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

            function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
                return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                }
            });
            var item_id = $(this).attr("item_id");
            var partner_id = $(this).attr("partner_id");
            var quantity = $(this).attr("quantity");
            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"/sud/trade_action/",
                 data: {
                        'partner': "container",
                        'id': partner_id,
                        'goods_id': item_id,
                        'csrftoken': csrftoken,
                        'quantity': quantity
                        },
                 success: function(data){
                         $('#output').html(data);
                 }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Note how button attribute "quantity" is updated on slider change. For some reason I could not address the slider directly with $('#slider_'.concat(item_id)).val(); might me the problem that brought me here initially. For general purposes I would still like to know how to address elements of one ajax generated DOM (if I'm putting this correctly) with a script in another ajax generated DOM.

This is the code that updates item info on hover:

```
$(".item_description").hover(function(){
             if ($(this).attr("data") == "empty")
             {
                 $(this).attr("data", "loaded");
                 var param;
                 var partner_id = $(this).attr("partner_id");
                 param = $(this).attr("d_id");
                 $.get('/sud/item_na/', {id: param, list_type: 'char', 'partner_id': partner_id}, function (data) {
                     $('#i_descr_'.concat(param)).html(data);
                 });
             }
         });
```

Comment: I believe this is because, the dom doesnt exist when the script in the main page is run. I suggest adding this code to your ajax's success function instead after the div is updated in code and rendered to DOM.

Comment: you can use also beforeSend parameter of jquery ajax call

Comment: @Arathi Sreekumar I tried following your advice, but it behaves the same, details updated in the main post. I could have the syntax wrong though, I have next to none experience with js.

Comment: Can you share the ajax code? The code that updates the above template to DOM in ajax, and basically the whole ajax request response part would be best.

Comment: what is in data? is it the div with the trade-move class? Or is it the template. If its the template, try console logging within the trade move click, the value of sliderElem  before the if slideElem. I think that might be where it's failing. Let me know if its undefined.

Comment: @Arathi Sreekumar I got it working, but the result strongly reminds me of duct tape and kludges. All attempts to get the slider value return undefined indeed, even from the same template with the slider, I have no idea why.

Comment: Yes, the more I looked at it the more reminded of spagetti I became. This might need some serious rethinking. The architecture of it I mean. Doesn't seem like a clean solution. Maybe have more data handling done on the backend or store as js objects so that so much information needn't be DOM dependent. There might be 'this' related issues too.

Comment: @Arathi Sreekumar I totally appreciate any advice, it's like the first front end of that sort I've ever been making )

Answer (score 0):

You could add a pseudo-class, `js-slider` in your input element:

```
<input class="slider js-slider" type="range" 
      item_id="{{description.id}}" 
      id="slider_{{description.id}}" 
      min="0" max="{{description.slider}}" 
      value="{{description.slider}}" step="1">
```

and then you this class in order to grab your element.

```
$(".trade_move").click(function() {
    var item_id = $(this).attr("item_id");
    var partner_id = $(this).attr("partner_id");
    var quantity = 1;
    var sliderElem = $(".js-slider");
    if (sliderElem) {
        quantity = sliderElem.val();
    }
}
```

In the above code, I think that it is evident that `item_id` and `partner_id` are not used. So you can eliminate them. Furthermore, I don't see where you use the `quantity`.

Comment: I actually have a list of elements, each with its own button and hover-activated info window, which is the one ajax updated. So you don't have to load all data for all list elements, but for those the user hovers over only. The info has the slider input to set a value, and which is supposed to go to the server for further processing. I did not include this request code as not relevant to the question.

Comment: As to your suggestion, I need item id field for distinguishing list elements and the slider already has the slider class, why not use it? Also, the class then has a lot of items, any way to get one with specific id? I suppose it will have the same problem with element not existing when the main page is loaded.